# Rendering response from a socket

Tags: sockets, reactjs

I am using a socket to connect to my database. The initial response, is a list of messages.

I would like it to show this list of messages, and then allow more messages to be be added below of course.

I think I see the issue. JSON.parse is returning an array and I'm adding it to the array. So in render the code is expecting "item" to be an object but it's actually the array of objects.

How is the correct way to render this initial data/response from the socket?

```
class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: []
      };
    }
  componentWillMount () {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/chat/super/');
    socket.addEventListener('message', 
        event => {this.setState(prev=>({ 
            data: [...prev.data, event.data ? JSON.parse(event.data) : {}] 
    }))
    });

    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    // THIS data is the response, which I want to show as the immediate array
    });
    }
    render() 
    {
        return  <div>
  {this.state.data.map(item=>(
    <div key={item.timestamp}>
        <h1 key={item.handle}>{item.handle}</h1>
            <li key={item.message}>{item.message}</li>
        </div>))}
    </div>

    ;}
    }

export default connect()(Chat);
```

Comment: you listening to the same event twice? i think that would make any event handle twice too, is that intended? if you want to display the event.data, just  call setState. it will trigger re-rendering

Comment: Yes I realise I"m listening twice, I was trying to console.log() the response.

Please show me how to call the set state with an example

Comment: componentWillMount() {
      ...
      // always make sure before setting the state here
      // that your data is available
      this.setState({ data: [...event.data ] })
    }

Answer (score -1):

As Rei Dien pointed out, you've got duplicate event listeners so remove the second one. Also, state changes and data fetches should be done in `componentDidMount` so that they properly trigger re-renders. I've also cleaned up your code for legibility purposes.

```
class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/chat/super/');

    socket.addEventListener('message', event => {
      // console.log(event)
      this.setState({
        data: [
          ...prev.data, 
          event.data ? ...JSON.parse(event.data) : {}
        ] 
      })
    });
   }

   render() {
     return  (
       <div>
         {this.state.data.map(item => (
           <div key={item.timestamp}>
             <h1 key={item.handle}>{item.handle}</h1>
             <li key={item.message}>{item.message}</li>
           </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default connect()(Chat);
```

Comment: I keep getting syntax errors on this one, at `render(){`

Comment: what babel presets/plugins are you using?

Comment: ah, it's missing some closing tags... I'll edit the answer.

Comment: add the tag at the end of `componentDidMount`

Comment: That example did not work at all. It removed my items from listing, and did not load the data from the initial state

Comment: Sounds like you've got other problems.

Comment: It is listing now, the code you provided does not get the initial response and render it still. It starts blank still

Comment: Web requests can take time, is the server local?

Comment: Yes local. The console log shows the json data immediately that needs to show

Comment: hmm, I've changed a few of the ways you had functions laid out in the example. without having the whole code I can't be of much help.

Comment: That is the whole code. It is a very simple attempt on a socket

Comment: try adding the spread operator before JSON.parse(event.data) like I've done in the example.

Comment: I have pasted your entire example and it really is no different from mine

Comment: Appreciate the attempt

Comment: I think I see the issue. JSON.parse is returning an array and I'm adding it to the array. So in render your code is expecting "item" to be an object but it's actually the array of objects. How would I fix that?

Comment: ...JSON.parse()

Comment: Happy to accept your answer should you edit/update it with the spread. Thanks